# Geofence with fused location

Tags: android, gps, android-geofence, android-fusedlocation

I am developing an application in which I have to make the geofencing but with Fused location may or may not be GPS signal available.

With the available example of geofencing, It shows **Geofence service is not available now** when gps becomes off.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

I want to get the location from fused location for Geofencing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I used FusedLocationApi before, here is some code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzCeun34V4j7djdySVBZaDFkdTA?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide me access of this folder.

Comment: here is another link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzCeun34V4j7djdySVBZaDFkdTA?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you use Geofencing in emulator you get error message like `Geofence service is not available now`. Try using an app like [Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en)
to mock location/trip and then use Geofencing.